# Rails 4 link_to option to include data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

i have a link as follows

```
<a title="" class="btn btn-default btn-icon btn-xs tip" href="#" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
```

what i have tried?

```
<%= link_to "<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>".html_safe, edit_admin_category_path(category), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-icon btn-xs tip', :data => {:original-title=>"Edit"} %>
```

Error:

```
/Users/harshamv/Sites/nomad/app/views/admin/categories/index.html.erb:28: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
```

Is there a way to use link_to without have to  use the following format

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will work, it's just a syntax error where you need to fix the double quotes.

```
<%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, edit_admin_category_path(category), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-icon btn-xs tip', :data => {:original-title=>"Edit"} %>
```

You could also use `content_tag` which is a little cleaner

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:li, '', class: 'fa fa-pencil'), edit_admin_category_path(category), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-icon btn-xs tip', :data => {:original-title=>"Edit"} %>
```